# update using foreach loop php

Tags: php, foreach

```
if(isset($_POST['Active']) && isset($_POST['Box'])){ 

    $status= $_POST['activation'];

    foreach($_POST['Box'] as $remove_ch){


        $sqlupd= "update Pre_Enrollment set Status='$status' where Checkbox_Id='$remove_ch'";
        $resultupdate = mysqli_query($database,$sqlupd) or die (mysqli_error($database));

        if($resultupdate){
            echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=\"0; URL=../Admin/admin pre-enrollment.php\">";
        }

    }

}
```

from this code, i need to update the status using checkbox but its update only the last row I have, and then it allows me to update the rest with the same choice of first one, considering that status are option list. can you please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Use a `header` in place of the `meta`. You set the status outside of the loop. Is there only one status field? You could just use an `in` and update all the records at once. You are open to SQL injections, parameterize the query. Also do you have `Active` and `activation` inputs?

Comment: I have active and inactive options. and "Active" is the button, "Activation" is the name of the option.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Comment: how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please be careful, you might be exposed to SQL injection. Concatenating strings is not the best option, try running parametrized queries.

Secondly, how does the  tag look like?
A common mistake is to forget "[]" after the field. An example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Box[]" value="{ID}">
```

Thirdly, `echo "<meta..>"` should probably be outside of the foreach loop.

Comment: what are the parametrized queries.? and echo "<meta..>"?

Comment: About SQL injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: By `echo "<meta..>"` I was referring to your refresh meta tag. If you keep it inside the loop, it'll be printed once for every item in $_POST['Box'].